# Exportar Datatable a tabla access en un único InsertCommand?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Estoy realizando una carga masiva de datos desde un Datatable a una tabla en Access.
El problema/dilema es que tengo que recorrer cada Datarow del Datatable y a través de un InsertCommand cargo cada row en la tabla.

El código que utilizo es el siguiente:

```
    Dim adapter As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim comand As OleDbCommand

    comand = New OleDbCommand(sqlStr, conn7)
    adapter.InsertCommand = comand
    adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Pregunta: Hay alguna forma para realizar un único InsertCommand con todos los registros del Datatable en vez de tener que recorrerlo e ir 1 a 1 y lanzar el respectivo InsertCommand??

Muchas gracias de antemano,

Un saludo

Comment: Si tienes los datos a insertar en un DataSet, puedes usar [`Update`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dataadapter.update?view=net-6.09)

Comment: Con el Update no hay problema, también tengo desarrollado un método que injecta la sql directamente en BBDD y me carga la info en la tabla.
La historia es que tengo que repetir dicho proceso más de 150.000 veces, de ahí la cosa de volcar directamente todos los registros del Datatable en una única vez.
Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: El metodo Update actualiza o inserta dependiendo de lo necesario, asi que sirve tambien para insertar

Answer (score 0):

Al final lo he solucionado utilizando un comand, añadiéndole parámetros y utilizando el ExecuteNonQuery.

Funciona bastante bien y rápido (pero se realiza registro a registro):

El código que he utilizado es el siguiente:

```
Public Sub AddDataToTableAccess(dtInfo As DataTable, conn6 As OleDbConnection)        
Dim comand As OleDbCommand
    comand = New OleDbCommand()

    comand = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO " & table1 & "(field1) values (@value1)", conn)
    comand.Parameters.Add("@value1", OleDbType.Integer)

    For i = 0 To dtInfo.Rows.Count - 1
        comand.Parameters("@value1").Value = dtInfo.Rows(i).Item(0)
        comand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Next
End Sub
```

field1: Nombre de la columna deseada de la tabla de Access.

value1: Valor que quiero añadir a la columna field1 de la tabla table1.

table1: Nombre de la tabla de access a que quiero insertar la información.

Espero que ayude